# How to extract the bin width from a Histogram made with an automatic binning method?

Tags: list-manipulation, histograms, version-7

I am using the Scott binning method with `Histogram` and `Histogram3D` to plot some data. How could I find out the bin width chosen by *Mathematica*?

I am using version 7 and thus I cannot use `HistogramList`.

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer for a version 7 solution.

Answer (score 4):

In version 8 and above, `HistogramList` will give you a list of bin delimiters and counts, so you need to just pass it the same options you pass to `Histogram` and `Histogram3D`. For example,

```
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200], "Scott"]
(* {{-(7/2), -3, -(5/2), -2, -(3/2), -1, -(1/2), 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2}, 
    {1, 0, 5, 10, 16, 34, 39, 40, 39, 9, 7}} *)
```

---

For version 7, which does not have `HistogramList`, you can generate the histogram and get the bin info from the rectangles used in the plot. For example,

```
histogramList[x_] := Transpose@Cases[x, RectangleBox[{bl_, _},{br_, c_}] :> {{bl, br}, c}, ∞];
hist = Histogram[RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 200], "Scott"];
{bins, counts} = histogramList@hist

(* {{{-3, -(5/2)}, {-(5/2), -2}, {-2, -(3/2)}, {-(3/2), -1}, {-1, -(1/2)}, {-(1/2), 0}, 
     {0, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 3/2}, {3/2, 2}, {2, 5/2}, {5/2, 3}}, 
    {2, 3, 13, 19, 29, 34, 40, 28, 19, 10, 2, 1}} *)
```

Note that the above gives you the bin interval pairs, instead of just the delimiters. If you want it in the same format as `HistogramList` in version 8, then just use `Flatte@DeleteDuplicates` on `bins`.